# How to access new Room Tasks via Tasks API (or other Google API)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace, google-tasks-api, google-chat

G Suite users have recently gained access to an integrated Gmail interface. In this interface, Google Chat's rooms now have their own Tasks integration

Has anyone found resources for accessing and working with these Chat Room Tasks via an API. I'm especially interested in working with Apps Script.

I just ran a list API call on my tasklists, and I only see the lists I've made directly in Google Tasks. There is no indication of the lists associated with my Google Chat Rooms.

Comment: It is anew feature being rolled out from yesterday, from what I can [read](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/). Give it some time until it's implemented in the APIs.

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's like that until further notice.

Comment: hey, @ziganotschka I was trying to find the resource on this API for google chat and Tasks. Do we have anything yet ?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the feature request for this. If anyone is interested they can track this feature here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173343990

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do so with Google API, and given it has been 3 years, it's unlike they will. But there are ways to do it manually, which involves a lot of trial and error and this  is the gist of it. Basically, it boils down to 3 things.

1. Find the container and copy the outer HTML.
2. Each task is contained by a div with `aria-label` attribute. It contains the task description
3. Run xidel on the outer HTML. the one found working for me is:

```
$ xidel tasks.html --extract "for $label in /html/body/div/div/div/@aria-label return replace($label, '\n', '-') " > tasks.txt
```

This gives you a list of tasks in the file, where each line represents a task. From there, you can use sed/awk to get the task and assignee separated. This is what I found working

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)assigned to \(.*\)/\2\t\1/' tasks.txt
```

```
$ grep assigned.to tasks.txt  | sed 's/\(.*\)assigned to \(.*\)/\2\t\1/' | awk -F $'\t' '$1== "John Smith" {print $2;}'
```